How to maintain different releases in GitHub Flow branching strategy?
I am trying to choose GitHub Flow branching strategy for my project (as explained here and everywhere on the internet) since we are only two developers in the project
The only confusion I have is, how to maintain different releases in this branching strategy.
There is no mention of it.
I like the idea of creating a tag in the main branch in GitFlow branching strategy after a release from the main branch to indicate a release.
This is written there

The branch can be tagged at various commits in order to signify
different versions or releases of the code

But nothing of this sort is mentioned anywhere for GitHub flow. Even nothing is mentioned about how to maintain different or previous releases code.
So can I use tagging of the main branch to maintain releases in GitHub strategy even when GitHub strategy description does not say this?
I basically just want to make sure I won't be breaking the standard GitHub branching strategy rules if I use main branch tagging for releases.

Yes. A relase or version is associated with some name like v1.5.0. And
that is concretely represented as a Git Tag, typically and specifically
an annotated tag. This is standard practice to the point that it is not
always spelled out.
Maintaining previous releases
But a tag is a static thing. It doesn’t help you with making changes
specific to that version; it doesn’t help you with maintenance.
I would advocate this scheme:

The next-release branch is the main branch. This already falls out of
GitHub Flow
Create maintenance branches on a per-need basis: check out the tag and
create a maintenance branch on the form maintenance-<tag name> (or
whatever naming scheme you like)

Let’s real concretely say that you are on v2.0 and the previous
version was v1.8. Now you need to support consumers who are on v1.8
but who cannot update to v2.0. It just so happens that you have a bug
to fix that is vital for the version coming after v1.8… which is not
v2.0 in this case but something like v1.8.1:
v2.0  v1.8.1
|    /
v1.8

Well really you want this fix to be both in the upcoming versions v2.0
and v1.8.1.

Create a branch on tag v1.8 named maintenance-v1.8
Do the bug fix on this branch
Merge maintenance-v1.8 into the main branch
Now both of the paralell branches have this bug fix

Further reading
See the “Managing Branches” section of man gitworkflows.
